# "meteor" shortcut not working over SSH

Tags: meteor, putty

I created an admin user ("win7desktop") on my iMac.  As that user, I installed meteor.js and created a project ("coolApp").

Then I went to my Windows PC and (using PuTTY) logged into my iMac via SSH as user "win7desktop".  I navigated to "coolApp" and tried entering "meteor", but that gives me "command not found".  I can enter "/usr/local/bin/meteor", and that seems to work.

What did I do wrong?  How do I make the "shortcut" work?

Comment: your PATH variable is wrong when you ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your path isn't being set up properly when you ssh over!
if running:

```
which meteor
```

returns nothing (or an error), then you can run

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/meteor
```

to temporarily add it to your path. If that works out, you may want to add that above line to your ~/.bashrc file, so its run whenever your shell starts.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  I added PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin to my ~/.bashrc, and everything's working great.

Comment: Nice to know everythings great now!